# Change ID and Class by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating visual configurator for a car and wheels.

The whole rests of two variables, basic is a car, next one is wheels.
I have two columns with buttons of cars and wheels. When i select own options, website show right individual picture.

I thought, that car is #ID element, whhels is .Class element
When i selecting cars, ID is changing, when i selecting wheels Class is changing

Something like this:

```
<div id="car_2" class="wheel_5">
```

I tried to removeID, removeClass by .click(function(), but doesn't work.
How can i do that. I have 15 cars and 4 wheels.

Can you help me?

Comment: Show the code snippet with the problem, pls.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found solution
If anybody won's to remove ID and add noweone by click he cna use this

```
$( "#car_2_button" ).click(function() {
    $("#visualization div").removeAttr("id"); //remove ID
    $("#visualization div").attr("id", "car_2"); //adding new ID
});
```

The same code is working with class

```
$( "#wheel_2_button" ).click(function() {
    $("#visualization div").removeAttr("class"); //remove class
    $("#visualization div").attr("id", "wheel_2"); //adding new class
});
```

Comment: Well done for working out your own solution. Good work. Know that the kind of jQuery you are writing here is just as easily written (and arguably better) in vanilla **ES2015**: `document.querySelector('#car_2_button').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('#visualization div').setAttribute('id', 'car_2), false);` It's not that jQuery is bad - it's not, it's very good. But jQuery was created to solve a lot of syntax / incompatibility problems that JS had in the mid-2000s... which it no longer has.